# Showing an Image based on Catagoy ID or a specific Attribute is YES in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a image that shows up in all catagorys BUT I would like to have a different image show up based on the current catagory ID - and or if the product atttribute equals YES in Magento

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have uploaded an image in root category. So it might apear in all categories.
To set different images for different categories,go to that category and upload the image as you wish.